# preg_match question

Tags: php, regex

I need a preg_match expression for string and character "/". Please string1/string2/string3 pattern for example or string1/strin2. Just the same preg match for string and character "/". Alone in the network can not find any generator, so maybe someone will know.

work witch king reply thank

Comment: Perhaps you could eleborate with some examples of what would return true and return false

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = explode("/", $your_string);
```

will do the stuff

Answer (score 1):

```
~^[0-9A-Za-z/]+$~
```

should do it. Note, that the regular expression need delimiters (Here `~`).

Comment: What if the string is `"Bananas!/I love bananas"`?

Comment: The op provided some examples, that let me assume, that there is no whitespace and punctuation within the string. However, it is not that hard to add it ;) On the other side when we allow _every_ sign, you don't need a validation (except `strlen($string) > 0`) at all, thus there must be some limitations. To answer your question: It's `false`